# Question Mark Replaced by É

Tags: windows-xp, fonts, microsoft-outlook-2003

This happens occasionally. Today it happened in a calendar item in outlook 2003. As you can see from the title here, the question mark is working here (Firefox).

I am typing and suddenly the question mark is replaced by this character, É and I have no idea why. How can I sotp this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a second keyboard layout configured and you occasionally trip over the keybinding to switch layouts. Go to the keyboard or international control panel and remove the extra layout.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't find this. I went to control panel and looked at the keyboard and saw nothing that resembles what you said. I have, on occasion used the character map for certain characters. Could that trigger what you said, and if so, how could I deal with it?
Regards,

Comment: `Regional and Language Options` | `Languages` | `Details`

Comment: Found that immediately after I commented. My key board has 3 languages: Canadian French, Canadian multi-language and US. Are they what you are referring to?
Thanks again.

Comment: Correct. Sounds like you only need the US English layout.

Comment: Having my region set to Canada, one of the things I hate most on Windows is the *random* assumption that I will want to switch to French halfway through typing my document. Non, merci!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too! Hitting cntrl+shift didn't help, unlike many articles suggested. I decided to ask the Help Bot in Windows Settings, and there I got the information that you may press Windows+spacebar repeatedly to change your settings. Surprisingly, it worked!
Please tell me if it worked for you, too.